# How to change database that with web configuration is created?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to change database that web configuration is created?

When I use Asp.net Configuration, visual studio create a default data base (ASPNETDB.MDF),
 I want use my database for my web site .

How to do this?

Comment: I've tidied your question a bit but I'm really struggling to understand what you mean

Comment: ok.Tanks for your attention.I cant speak english very good but my friend reply to my  question below :)

Answer (score 0):

You should a  add database using this line in web.config

replace with aspnetdb connection string

```
    <connectionStrings>
  <add name="LoanCalculatorConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=dbname;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=888;Password=8888"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I am insert this code to web config , but when use web configuration , add a new database again

Comment: can you give me web.config file

Comment: I reply to this question below.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this tab in `<connectionStrings>` of your `Web.Config`

```
<connectionStrings>    
<add name="YourConnectionStringName"  
connectionString="DataSource=yourDataSource;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;User ID=YourID;Password=YourPassword"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />    
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I am insert this code to web config , but when use web configuration , add a new database again

Comment: `add a new database again` ? what it is mean ?

Answer (score -1):

To this porpus use this way:

C://windows/Microsoft.net/Framework/v2.0.50727/aspnet_regsql.exe

. is run

Next--> Configuration SQL server for application service --> select server and database --> Next --> Finish